# convert string to existing variable

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python, and I am making a sudoku game. I want to be able to add two strings together and then turn it into a variable I already have defined. For example:

```
abc1 = 0
abc2 = 0
abc3 = 0
rownum = 0
```

Then when rownum is a row number,
The game will add "abc" and rownum together so that it will output abc joined with rownum (If rownum was 1 it will output abc1) and the output would be a variable (so the value could be edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a list instead:

```
abc = [1, 2, 3] # Read more about lists
rownum = 0
```

So if `rownum` is 1, you may want to print or whatever you want `abc[rownum]`, which will be `abc[1]`.

Remember that lists index starts with 0:

```
print abc[0]
>>> 1
print abc[1]
>>> 2
print abc[2]
>>> 3
```

Comment: But will i be able to change the value then?

Comment: To change the value of what?

Comment: The items in the list

Comment: Thank you! also sorry if i have some spelling mistakes, i am on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this is what you need:

`output = 'abc' + str(rownum)`

Comment: yeah, and I need the output to be a variable name

Comment: That's the part I don't fully understand. what do you mean you want output to be a variable name?

Comment: the output would be a variable like output = 1 + output